# How to show image in image view from URL coming from Push notification

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to shoe image in view based on URL, but  url is coming as push notification, i am getting all PNS properly, also got image URL successfully but image is not displaying properly. below code i am using when i got new push notification i am opening that notification and calling methods whch is in another view where i want to set image.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Have a Notification :\n%@",userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}
NSLog(@"Payload: %@", userInfo);
imageURL =  userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
MainViewController *mv =  [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [mv  sshowansimage:imageURL]; // CALL METHOD OF ANTOHER CLASS WHERE I WANT TO SET IMAGE

}
```

now here is code for  sshowansimage method which is mainviewcontrriler class

```
-(void) sshowansimage:(NSString *) strImageURL{


NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImageURL];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        imgeview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the URL?. Just pass the url as argument.

Comment: i have added parameter just check that code

Comment: Log the URL and try it in the browser.

Comment: Tried but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void) sshowansimage:(NSString *) strImageURL{

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImageURL];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImage:) withObject:imageData waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

}

```
-(void)showImage:(NSData*)imageAsData
{
imgeview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageAsData];
}
```

always perform UI related task in main thread

Comment: If possible post here that image URL

Comment: http://www.vijaywebsolutions.com/Development_FTP/Nilesh/amin/app/detail-page-screen-7.jpg

Comment: above comment i have posted thiat URL

Comment: My above code works perfect with given URL. I don't know where you do mistake If you want I can send you zip

Comment: hi, its working when i am calling -(void) sshowansimage:(NSString *) strImageURL from view didload but not working from didreceiveremotenotification, any ideas??

Comment: i have accepted your answer, but its not caliing from didreceive notification

Comment: did you receive imageData successfully. check it's length

Comment: means? i am not getting you

Comment: NSlog(@"%d",imageData.length);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40804/discussion-between-user2902101-and-anand-k)

Comment: Here is correct code, MainViewController *MvC=[[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewControlleripad" bundle:nil]; 
self.window.rootViewController=MvC; 
[MvC sshowansimage:imageURL];